# Is anything faster than or equally as fast as MATLAB's cellfun( ) function in Python for complex matrix operations?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix, cell

I am performing some complex matrix operations on an array of matrices. When I do it using MATLAB's cellfun( ) function, it takes 0.1 seconds. In Python, whether I use loop or map function or list comprehension, the same operation takes around 0.6 seconds.

For example, variable **vector** is an array containing matrices. The matrices in the vector do not have similar dimensions (stored as object datatype in Python).

Example code in Python:

```
mat1=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
mat2=np.array([[1,2,1],[3,4,3],[5,6,5]])
mat3=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
vector=np.array([mat1,mat2,mat3],dtype=object)
result=np.array(np.ones(3),dtype=object)
i=0
for v in vector:   
    result[i]=np.mean(v,1)
    i=i+1
```

Example code in MATLAB:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) mean(x,2),vector,'uni',0)
```

Is there any other way to speed up the process in Python?

Comment: Please show example of your Python code.

Comment: @NotAName Code edited to the post for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing it in a for-loop. If you use `np.mean(vector, 1)` it will return means for all sub-arrays along the selected dimension.

Comment: As a general rule, if you're using numpy and loops you're doing it wrong. You can also check out Numpy's `apply_along_axis()` method which should be similar to how `cellfun` works

Comment: Thanks! `np.mean(vector, 1)` will work there. What should I do if there are multiple operations involved? For example, using `repmat()`, then transforming axes and finally taking the mean.

Comment: @NotAName . Oh, I forgot to mention that matrices contained in the vector array do not have same dimensions. Therefore, vector is an array of object datatype.

Comment: Python is not as fast as MATLAB. But if you want help from the Python experts here, you should give them a [mre]: write a few lines of code that create the `vector` object (e.g. with random data in it). Otherwise people will make assumptions about what that is, and likely you’ll get answers that are not useful to you.

Comment: I was also thinking about messing up my explanation. Thank you so much for your comment. @CrisLuengo

Comment: Have updated the code. @CrisLuengo, does this help? Thanks. But, makes me think what you said about MATLAB being faster than Python.

Comment: Also note that `for` loops in Matlab are usually faster than `cellfun` and `arrayfun`, which mainly exist for convenience.

Comment: So is MATLAB loop faster than a Python loop? @horchler